# how to fix mysql error number #1250 Table 'a1' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list?

Tags: mysql, union

I am doing following way to sorting data by date and time

```
select b.app_user_id,b.username,a.message_content,a.message_to,a.message_date 
from app_messages a 
left join app_users b 
on a.message_from = b.app_user_id
where a.message_to=1 and b.app_user_id= 4
UNION 
select b1.app_user_id,b1.username,a1.message_content,a1.message_to,a1.message_date 
from app_messages a1 
left join app_users b1 
on a1.message_from = b1.app_user_id 
where a1.message_to=4 and b.app_user_id= 1 
order by a1.message_date,a.message_date
```

here my table structure 
[image: table app_messages]
[image: table app_users]
I get mysql error number #1250 Table 'a1' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list

how to sorting data with unioun clause correctly as my case?

Comment: Did you try "... order by message_date" ?

Comment: Yes I do,  I fix my problem with @fa06 answer

Comment: The answer from @fa06 requires that the query result is first stored in a temporary  table, and the this temporary table is read to generate the end result.  This is unnecessary overhead.  All you need is to make sure to give the same name (alias) to columns of both query, and then use this name in the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: please give me an answer to optimizing my sql script like your explanation @oysteing

Comment: I am already give same alias of both query replacing "a1 and b1" to be  "a and b" but the result still display same, error number #1250

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below - you need to use order by clause in outer query

```
select * from
(
select b.app_user_id,b.username,a.message_content,a.message_to,a.message_date 
from app_messages a 
left join app_users b 
on a.message_from = b.app_user_id
where a.message_to=1 and b.app_user_id= 4
UNION 
select b1.app_user_id,b1.username,a1.message_content,a1.message_to,a1.message_date 
from app_messages a1 
left join app_users b1 
on a1.message_from = b1.app_user_id 
where a1.message_to=4 and b1.app_user_id= 1 
)A order by message_date
```

Comment: not work bro, and now I get #1054 - Unknown column 'b.app_user_id' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1):

If not otherwise specified, column names in result will be determined by first query of union.  Hence, this query should do what you want:

```
select b.app_user_id,b.username,a.message_content,a.message_to,a.message_date 
from app_messages a 
left join app_users b 
on a.message_from = b.app_user_id
where a.message_to=1 and b.app_user_id= 4
UNION 
select b1.app_user_id,b1.username,a1.message_content,a1.message_to,a1.message_date 
from app_messages a1 
left join app_users b1 
on a1.message_from = b1.app_user_id 
where a1.message_to=4 and b.app_user_id= 1 
order by message_date;
```